# Re-order reminder accounts in OS X

Tags: macos

In the sidebar of the Reminders app for OS X, you can see your accounts and then the lists of reminders in each account.

How can I change the order in which the accounts appear? (Not the lists within each account.)

Answer (score 1):

You can't re-order the accounts. The order of the list of accounts can't be modified without deleting and re-adding the account.